# Static functions vs const functions

Tags: c++, static-methods

I'm looking at a member function

```
int funct(int x) const;
```

And I'm wondering if

```
static int funct(int x);
```

would be better.

If a member function doesn't use any of the member variables should it be static? Are there any things that would discourage this?

Comment: A collogue of mine suggested that the const way allows for polymorphism.  That is interesting. Thoughts?

Comment: Why is this a community Wiki?

Comment: Because there isn't really an answer. (beyond the one my mate proposed) and I don't like having questions rated. In the past a technical|specific|answerable questions has lost me points. 

I don't give a hoot about my personal points, but I felt personally invalidated.

If I ask a T|S|A, I lose. If I ask a "what is your fav...", I gain. My understanding is community wiki leaves my points alone.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Assuming this is C++, a function declared as const indicates that it does not intend to change data members on the instance on which it is called, i.e., the this pointer. Since there are ways to evade this, it is not a guarantee, merely a declaration.

A static function does not operate on a specific instance and thus does not take a "this" pointer. Thus, it is "const" in a very naive way.

If your method does not need to be bound to a specific instance, it makes sense to make it static.

However, if your method is polymorphic - that is, you provide a different implementation based on the instance of the object on which it is invoked, then it cannot be static, because it does depend on a specific instance.

Comment: Yeah. I talked to my co-workers and we came to the same thought.  Thanks.

Comment: And you cannot do a v-table lookup without knowing the `this` pointer

Answer (score 9):

If a member function doesn't use any of the member variables it is often worth asking the question:
 "Does this need to be a member function in the first place?"

Comment: I always stick to this rule. When a method doesn't use any members, state it as static. But my boss insist const is better a static, maybe for some multithreading reason. But I don't know the exact reason.

Comment: Just as a Time class, it can have mumbers like hour, minute and second. When the method Now() returns the current time, it dones't have relationship with these members. So it is supposed to be a static.